# How to figure out the name to specify in import statement in Swift

Tags: swift, cocoapods

Every time I import a Cocoapods library I have trouble in finding out what name to specify in the import statement.

First of all, should we always explicitly import the Cocoapods in all the files using the library? 
If that's the case how can we find the name to specify in the import statement?

**EDIT**

Thanks for the answer about the necessity of import statement when using a library. I'm now completely clear about that.

About the package name, it seems like most of the Pods have a file with the extension ".modulemap" in their Support Files directory, and that is the one which specifies the module name. Is my understanding correct?  It looks right but at the same time I have a doubt as well because some Pods(for example Fabric, GoogleSignIn etc.) don't have that.

Answer (score 0):

> should we always explicitly import the Cocoapods in all the files using the library?

Yes of course! If you don't import a module, you won't be able to use the types defined in the module.

> how can we find the name to specify in the import statement?

Usually, this is the same as the name f the pod you write in your `Podfile`. The authors of most pods do this to avoid confusion. The names can be different though.

A good way of finding the module name of a pod is to go to the pods project in the left pane:

[image]

Click that and you will see all the modules listed out. For example:

[image]

Use the names you see in the list.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I know it matches the Pod name in a normal case.  but as you mentioned it sometimes differs.  So I wanted to know what's the exact reference point to specify the name.

Comment: @TakeshiYokemura yeah, and you can look at the pods project to find out what you should use in an import statement.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Every time I import a Cocoapods library I have trouble in finding out what name to specify in the import statement.**

Sometimes it takes time to load pod installed in project as you had successfully installed a pod but when it comes to import name doesn't show 
For this I usually do is command + b (Build project) just build project when you install a pod

**or**

Just Re-Open Project file after Successfully installing pods

**2. Should we always explicitly import the Cocoapods in all the files using the library?**

Yes, you need to import the pod in controller without this you won't be able to use its feature

**3. how can we find the name to specify in the import statement**

Usually the name is same as of pod File like alamofire 
Pod AlamoFire and Import AlamoFire
if Still you find issues with name Check pod List installed In your project

Comment: Thanks!  As I commented to the other answer,  it's okay if the author names the package name same to the pod name, but I'll get lost if it's not the case.

Comment: if in case name is not same and it is also not appearing while you trying to import just build project once